# How to connect to SQL Server database and retrieve data using Razor in WebMatrix?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, razor, webmatrix

I am developing a website using **WebMatrix** in **Asp.net**. I have downloaded and installed **SQL Server** . Now I don't know how to create a database in SQL Server and how to connect to it using Razor Syntax/Method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebMatrix is easy to connect to SQL Server; there is an old tutorial that can lead you: [Connecting to a SQL Server or MySQL Database in WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/connecting-to-a-sql-server-or-mysql-database-in-webmatrix).

With regard to create a table in SQL Server, there are books on how to accomplish this task. The easy way is to use SQL Server Management Studio. Googling I have found this tutorial that maybe could help: [Creating databases using SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://mrbool.com/creating-databases-using-sql-server-management-studio-express/4672).

Comment: The first link you posted, "Connecting to a SQL Server", doesn't work.

Comment: @DanielAnderson: the link has been dismissed. Look if this surviving link to the old Asp.Net site could help: [Connecting to a Database](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/5-working-with-data#SB_ConnectingToADatabase).

Comment: Thanks for that.  What I'm trying to also do is figure out how to use stored procedures with Razor, including fetching a return/output value from the procedure.  Anything good on that?  I haven't found anything recent that's helpful.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work in razer and want to connect with data base and retrieve data.

```
var db = Database.Open("Employee");
var dbCommand = "SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE ID = '1'"; // Select the name where id=1
var row = db.QuerySingle(dbCommand);
if(row != null) 
{
     var employee_name = row.Name;
}
```